# Из DataGridView в List

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

Всем привет :)

Хотела бы узнать, как из DGV (самое последнее поле) перенести данные из второй колонки в список (скрин прикрепляю)? Данные вводятся пользователем и при нажатии Valider отправляются в список.

Мой код:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> listOfTrad = new List<string>();
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dataGridView2.Columns.Count));
        for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
            listOfTrad[a] = (string)dataGridView2[a, 1].Value;
        }
    }
```

Выдает ошибку привышения индекса..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `listOfTrad.Add(...)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я кажись устала :) спасибо вам! Но ошибка, к сожалению, сохранилась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно реализоваь через LINQ:

```
DataGridView dv = new DataGridView();
  dv.Columns.Add("dfdsf", "dfdsf");
  dv.Rows.Add("1");
  dv.Rows.Add("2");
  dv.Rows.Add("3");
  dv.Rows.Add("4");
  dv.Rows.Add("5");
  List<string> listOfTrad = new List<string>();
  dv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList<DataGridViewRow>().ForEach(cx => { 
  listOfTrad.Add(cx.ToString()); });
```

Answer (score 2):

listOfTrad.Add(...) и поменять местами индексы. Готовый вариант:

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> listOfTrad = new List<string>();
        for (int a = 0; a < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
            listOfTrad.Add((string)dataGridView2[1, a].Value);
        }
```